# Restore Database from Network Drive

Tags: sql-server-2008, restore

I not able to restore DB from maped Network Drive, Only from HDD initialized in Native OS,

my enviroment is MsSql2008 on Win2008R2 Standard (as virtual in VMware ESX4.1),

Win2008R2 Standard doesn't supports adding Networks drive(s) as HDD, RAM, Procesors on Runtime, these resources are accesible after enviroment restarted,

I could be able to import DB from another instance, but there are some another internal rulles that doesn't allows me that (middle and huge DB)

1) backup in OmniBack form or Full_Backup_File

2) no available space on HDD to copy dump on local enviroment for middle and huge DB

3) another crazy rulles about Network trafics from local end_user_PC, reduced DiskArea, for moving files betwees luns....

is there someone that solved this issue, or this issue is strictly rellated with resources from WinOS

EDIT:

Answer from Microsoft Q&A

SQL Server Management Studio -> Server Objects -> Backup Devices -> Add

Comment: You have a hardware problem: lack of HDD space etc. This would be the simplest solution

Comment: is in conflicts with internal rulles max is 30pct FreeSpace on HDD, there not possible to hold huge reserve for available HDD space, meaning for middle and huge DB

Comment: The internal rule stops you doing your job. Fix the rule.

Comment: hehehe :-) thanks, not possible in all cases go ahead against the wall, because always there exist another idiot that did that without thinking about that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We just had a similar problem and noted that we could use UNC-pathes to specify the source of a restore.

The restore is done by some account with rather restricted permissions and therefore it does not see the drive mappings you see.

To make it work in domain context, allowing read access to the backup file to the computer.

In other cases, when the machines aren't in the same domain giving read permission to the file to everyone might be the last resort.

**Edit:**

Good to know that there is a build in option to add backup devices. 
For DBAs it might be the preferred way, developers in restricted environments have sometimes to try other options depending on the rights they where given.

For the German version of SSMS. You find the tool mentioned by mKorbel at

```
SQL Server Management Studio -> Server Objects -> Sicherungsmedien -> Neues Sicherungsmedium...
```